# Play sound on hover with image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I trying to play sound on list hover or mouseenter . this list have img inside the  a

attribute

this it html code and js

```js
function playclip() 
{
  var audio = document.getElementsByTagName("audio")[0];
  audio.play();
}
```

```html
<ul id="nav1" class="widgeticons2">

  <li>
    <a onmouseover="playclip();" href="Statistics.aspx">
      <img src="../Styles/SMSKat/img/MOHM4ZImg/NEW_IMG/smslogo.png" />
        asdf2
    </a>
  </li>

  <li>
    <a onmouseover="playclip();" href="SMS.aspx">
     <img src="../Styles/SMSKat/img/MOHM4ZImg/NEW_IMG/smslogo.png" alt="" />
      asdfg1
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

once i put the mouse inside a  it play sound. Go to image and back to a  its play again

how to make sound play only one time until it go out the li  itself

Comment: I got `Server Error in '/' Application.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**html**

```
 <audio>
    <source src="../Styles/SMSKat/Sounds/Hover.mp3" />
    <source src="../Styles/SMSKat/Sounds/click.mp3" />
    <source src="../Styles/SMSKat/Sounds/click.ogg" />
</audio>

<ul id="nav1" class="widgeticons2">

  <li class="mtrack">
    <a href="Statistics.aspx">
      <img src="../Styles/SMSKat/img/MOHM4ZImg/NEW_IMG/smslogo.png" />
        asdf2
    </a>
  </li>

  <li class="mtrack">
    <a href="SMS.aspx">
     <img src="../Styles/SMSKat/img/MOHM4ZImg/NEW_IMG/smslogo.png" alt="" />
      asdfg1
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js">
```

**javascript**

```
function playclip(){
     var audio = document.getElementsByTagName("audio")[0];
              audio.play();
            }
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.mtrack').on('mouseenter',function(){
        if(!$(this).hasClass('.played')){
        playclip();
        $(this).addClass('.played');
        }
        });
$('.mtrack').on('mouseleave',function(){
    if($(this).hasClass('.played')){
    $(this).removeClass('.played');
    }
    });
    });
```

Comment: 0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: '$' is undefined

Comment: do you use jquery? if yes change $ to jQuery

Comment: sorry i am not familiar with javascript so tell me what i have to do

Comment: SCRIPT5009: 'jQuery' is undefined

Comment: i am C# Developer Using VS 2012 and ASP.NET and IE and Opera Browser win8

Comment: please ensure you've included jquery in your project, as well as the page.

Comment: I add it. and its play only one time only on entire ul/> and in page

Comment: you want it to play one time per li ?

Comment: yes i want it per li or a/> Mouseover one ever mouseover should run

Comment: Thanks it's solve my problem but there is no way with html and css only with out Jquery