# Play sound on long press that works for mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am looking for a solution that will allow me to play a sound file when long-pressing an image.

I see a lot of solutions for desktop (when hovering an image or div) view but nothing that works on mobile for the popular browsers.

That image is also a link, so when clicking on it, it should go to the link. When pressing long, it should play sound.

I tested this tutorial:
http://middleearmedia.com/demos/webaudio/playsoundbuffer.html

And also this one:
http://allwebco-templates.com/support/S_audio_onmouseover.htm

And also this:
[Play sound on hover with image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27936837/play-sound-on-hover-with-image)

But none of them allows me to hover on chrome mobile, it just marks the image but the sound doesn't play.

Any solution on this matter?

This is my site:
http://www.tenehealth.info/

You can see the mobile hovering works on desktop.

Comment: How do you hover over an image on mobile devices?

Comment: On mobile device chrome you can't play sounds without use explicitly clicking for it. To do so one hack is to set autoplay policy to no user gesture required at [link] (chrome://flags)

Comment: @Jerodev with a hoverboard oviously, duh.

Comment: Are you *seriously* asking how to use a hover event on a touch device...?

Comment: Unless you have a magic phone that can sense the tip of your finger floating above the screen, this is a physically impossible to answer question

Comment: to make it accurate, i mean that when a user press long on the element, it will play the sound. i will fix my question ..

Answer (score 0):

http://jsbin.com/lunaqaq/3/edit?html,js,output

```
var start = 0;
var mils = 1000;

$('a.selector')
.mousedown(function () {
  // Start the timer on mousedown.
  start = Date.now();
})
.mouseup(function () {
  // On mouseup, check how long it's been.
  if (Date.now() - start < mils) {
    console.log('short');
    window.location = $(this).attr('href');
  }
  else {
    console.log('long');
    $('audio#audio-player').get(0).play();
  }
})
.click(function (e) {
  // Make sure the default click behaviour doesn't happen.
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

[Here's a tutorial I found regarding mobile audio](https://stuff-things.net/2015/01/08/controlling-html5-audio-on-mobile-devices/), which shows a few methods. I've added the `elem.play()` bit into the code above.

Comment: I made my question clearer: "That image is also a link, so when clicking on it - it should go to the link, when pressing long - it should play sound."

Comment: @user3003106 Updated now with a response for new question

Comment: i don't see any sound file here ? the idea is when user press (on mobile) he will go to the link. if he press long - a sound file will play

Comment: Well you mentioned the mobile, then you mentioned the long press, so I answered that part of your question. You say you already have audio working, and you linked to an audio tutorial. Where it says `console.log('long');`, you can surely use your imagination to place in whatever audio playing code you wish?

Comment: Also how you go about playing audio is highly subjective. It may be triggering an `<audio>` element, or it may be loading it via HTTP, or it may be triggering it some completely other way. But then there are a million resources on the web, and SO questions, regarding triggering audio in JS